# Retrieving a Foreign Key value with django-rest-framework serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the django rest framework to create an API. 
I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='items')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

To create a serializer for the categories I'd do:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

... and this would provide me with:

```
[{'items': [u'Item 1', u'Item 2', u'Item 3'], u'id': 1, 'name': u'Cat 1'},
 {'items': [u'Item 4', u'Item 5', u'Item 6'], u'id': 2, 'name': u'Cat 2'},
 {'items': [u'Item 7', u'Item 8', u'Item 9'], u'id': 3, 'name': u'Cat 3'}]
```

How would I go about getting the reverse from an Item serializer, ie:

```
[{u'id': 1, 'name': 'Item 1', 'category_name': u'Cat 1'},
{u'id': 2, 'name': 'Item 2', 'category_name': u'Cat 1'},
{u'id': 3, 'name': 'Item 3', 'category_name': u'Cat 1'},
{u'id': 4, 'name': 'Item 4', 'category_name': u'Cat 2'},
{u'id': 5, 'name': 'Item 5', 'category_name': u'Cat 2'},
{u'id': 6, 'name': 'Item 6', 'category_name': u'Cat 2'},
{u'id': 7, 'name': 'Item 7', 'category_name': u'Cat 3'},
{u'id': 8, 'name': 'Item 8', 'category_name': u'Cat 3'},
{u'id': 9, 'name': 'Item 9', 'category_name': u'Cat 3'}]
```

I've read through the docs on [reverse relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations) for the rest framework but that appears to be the same result as the non-reverse fields.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can make use of this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491357/8536024

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Just use a related field without setting `many=True`.

Note that also because you want the output named `category_name`, but the actual field is `category`, you need to use the `source` argument on the serializer field.

The following should give you the output you need...

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='category', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'category_name')
```

Comment: what about retriving all the fields of catagory model??

Comment: if you want to retrieve all the fields of category model make the category serializer and have it in code like category_name = CategorySerliazer()

Comment: I tried to do this but i'm getting a error  `Relational field must provide a 'queryset' argument, or set read_only='True' `

Comment: or providing a queryset attribute if you want to support create/update, something like: `category_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='category', queryset=Category.objects.all())`    I suppose.

Comment: in my case `categories= CategorySerializer(source='category', read_only=True)` it works django 2.07

Comment: the serializer approach seems to work, but based on the logs, it seems to do an additional select for each relation it serializes (e.g. for each category name). any way to accomplish this with just a single db call?

Comment: If you get `AssertionError:...` use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530606/5403449

Comment: @Tom Christie In the question, the OP is looking for a `CategorySerializer` but the answers are showing an `ItemSerializer`. Why the difference here?

Comment: Instead of RelatedField, you should use ReadOnlyField, it still has the source parameter :)

Comment: @DjangoBlockchain that's not the case, my question is about creating the item serializer

Comment: But if category in Item is manyTomany field, then how we will render it in this serialization?

Answer (score 178):

In the DRF version 3.6.3  this worked for me

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.CharField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'category_name')
```

More info can be found here: [Serializer Fields core arguments](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: But you have to be ware cause it should threw NoneType error if the category field In the Item model is set to blank=True

Comment: @DesertCamel You can simply add `allow_null=True` to your serializer CharField to overcome this

Answer (score 42):

Another thing you can do is to:

- create a property in your `Item` model that returns the category name and
- expose it as a `ReadOnlyField`.

Your model would look like this.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='items')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def category_name(self):
        return self.category.name
```

Your serializer would look like this. Note that the serializer will automatically get the value of the `category_name` model property by naming the field with the same name.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
```

Answer (score 30):

this worked fine for me:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 18):

Simple solution
`source='category.name'` where `category` is foreign key and `.name` it's attribute.

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, ReadOnlyField
from my_app.models import Item

class ItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category_name = ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: This is very well explained and easy to implement

Answer (score 12):

**Worked on 08/08/2018 and on DRF version 3.8.2:**

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'category_name')
        fields = ('id', 'category_name', 'name',)
```

Using the Meta `read_only_fields` we can declare exactly which fields should be read_only. Then we need to declare the `foreign` field on the Meta `fields` (better be explicit as the mantra goes: [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

Answer (score 5):

This solution is better because of no need to define the source model. But the name of the serializer field should be the same as the foreign key field name

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='title')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'category')
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to *replace* the field of the ForeignKey (that displays the ID) you can still used the `__all__` syntax for convenience and simply over-write the field name as you see fit. For example:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # override the category field that would otherwise show an integer value 
    # for the ID with the field of that model you choose. "name" here.
    category = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='category.name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

IMO this is convenient b/c you can still use the `__all__` syntax to capture any added fields later. Anything that's getting overridden is manually done so and, if needing to be reverted, can be manually done some without changing any other syntax.