# Foreign key value in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

**models.py:**

```
class Station(models.Model):
    station = models.CharField()

class Flat(models.Model):
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, related_name="metro")
    # another fields
```

Then in **serializers.py**:

```
class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    station = serializers.RelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Station


class FlatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    station_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='station', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Flat
        fields = ('station_name',)
```

And I have an error:

> NotImplementedError: `RelatedField.to_representation()` must be implemented.
>   If you are upgrading from REST framework version 2 you might want `ReadOnlyField`.
>   I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retreiving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers), but it does not help me.
>   How to fix that?
>   Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using RelatedField for the Station.station field? Surely it should be CharField.

Comment: @DanielRoseman with ```station = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)``` the same problem

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`RelatedField` is the base class for all fields which work on relations. Usually you should not use it unless you are subclassing it for a custom field.

In your case, you don't even need a related field at all. You are only looking for a read-only single foreign key representation, so you can just use a `CharField`.

```
class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    station = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Station


class FlatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    station_name = serializers.CharField(source='station.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Flat
        fields = ('station_name', )
```

You also appear to want the `name` of the `Station` object in your `FlatSerializer`. You should have the `source` point to the exact field, so I updated it to `station.name` for you.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the most recent implementation.