# Unable to overload (override) DRF serializer's save() method (or other methods)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to override my serializer's `save()` method ([as per the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly)) to support bulk instance creation. At the moment, I have something that looks like this (skip the code if you like, it's just for context. The real issue is I can't make any of my own serializer methods).

#### serializers.py

```
class BulkWidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serialize the Widget data """

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200485/
    some_foreign_key = serializers.CharField(source='fk_fizzbuzz.name', read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = (
            'some_foreign_key',
            'uuid',
            'foobar',
        )
        # Normally we would set uuid to read_only, but then it won't be available in the self.validate()
        # method. We also need to take the validator off this field to remove the UNIQUE constraint, and
        # perform the validation ourselves.
        # See https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2996 and
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/36334825/3790954
        extra_kwargs = {
            'uuid': {'read_only': False, 'validators': []},
        }

    def validate(self, data):
        return super(WidgetSerializer, self).validate(self.business_logic(data))

    def save(self):
        print("---------Calling save-----------")
        more_business_logic()
        instances = []
        for widget in self.validated_data:
            instances.append(Widget(**self.validated_data))
        Widget.objects.bulk_create(instances)
        return instances
```

#### viewset.py

```
class WidgetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = BulkWidgetSerializer
    pagination_class = WidgetViewSetPagination
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def partial_update(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data,
                    many=isinstance(request.data, list),
                    partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        pdb.set_trace()
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then I get new Wiget instances in the database, but their properties indicate that the `more_business_logic()` call in `save()` didn't occur. However, I do get feedback indicating that `business_logic` in `validate()` call occurred.

I presume from this that I'm somehow still stuck with the `super` class's `save()`? How can I override this method?

### Edit:

When I rename `save()` to `newsave()` in both files, and try to call it in the ViewSet, I get:

> AttributeError: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'newsave'

What's going on? Inspecting with `pdb` at the breakpoint shows that it is indeed a `BulkWidgetSerializer`. Inspecting in the shell shows `newsave` is definitely a method of that class:

```
>>>'newsave' in [func for func in dir(BulkWidgetSerializer) if callable(getattr(BulkWidgetSerializer, func))]
True
```

**Moreover**, if I create my own test method in the serializer class:

```
def test_method(self):
    print("Successful test method")
```

I can't call that either!

```
>>> serializer.test_method()
AttributeError: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'test_method'
```

Comment: For situations like these you should consider using `pdb`. Can you show us the code where you map your viewset with the child serializer? Also, what parent serializer have your override?

Comment: Yes, I can't invoke `pdb` in a function I can't call unfortunately. What do you mean parent/child serializer? There's only one level of serializer.

Comment: Your code sample is too restricted. For what we know you could call a different serializer than the one you think you call.

Comment: I've added more code, and debugging output. The debugger shows that it is as described, and I'm still unable to implement a custom `save` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `BulkWidgetSerializer` is wrapped by `ListSerializer` which is default behavior of DRF. That's why your new methods are missing.

If you instantiate any subclass of `BaseSerializer` with kwarg `many=True` [the library wraps it](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L124) with new `ListSerializer` with `child` set to your `Serializer` class.

Because of that you cannot override `save()` method to get desired effect.
Try overriding `many_init` classmethod of your serializer to provide custom `ListSerializer` which implements desired behavior, [as shown in DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-initialization).

Secondly it's better to override `create()` or `update()` methods instead of `save()` which calls one of them.

Your implementation could look something like that:

```
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        more_business_logic()
        instances = [
            Widget(**attrs) for attrs in validated_data
        ]
        return Widget.objects.bulk_create(instances)
```

And then in `BulkWidgetSerializer`:

```
@classmethod
def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['child'] = cls()
    return CustomListSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

A gotcha: don't forget to pass the right kwargs from the parent to the child, eg `kwargs['child'] = cls( partial=kwargs.get('partial') )` if you rely on any of them in your child class during your overwritten methods to support bulk partial updates (eg `validate()`).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are instantiating your serializer with `many=True`. In this case the `ListSerializer` is instantiated internally (you can find the code for this in the class method [`rest_framework.serializers.BaseSerializer.many_init`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L129)).

Hence the `save()` method of the `ListSerializer` is called. If you must override the save method, first create a custom list serializer:

```
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def save(self):
         ...
```

Then add this custom list serializer to your `BulkWidgetSerializer` by specifying `list_serializer_class`:

```
class Meta:
    list_serializer_class = CustomListSerializer
```

As specified by others, it is better to override either the `create` or `update` methods instead of `save`

Answer (score 2):

You have been reading the wrong part of documentation and your approach is not correct.

> The default implementation for multiple object creation is to simply
>   call .create() for each item in the list. If you want to customize
>   this behavior, you'll need to customize the .create() method on
>   ListSerializer class that is used when many=True is passed.

This ensures your more_business_logic you want to happen will happen on each item you pass in that list.

As per the documentation - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create