# How to get foreignkey field name instead of id in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='catalog')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum,Count

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    # company_name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I am getting api like this..
Here i am getting id instead of company_name.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "soubhagya",
        "company_name": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "nihar",
        "company_name": 2
    }
]
```

But i am expecting output--

like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "soubhagya",
        "company_name": "google"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "nihar",
        "company_name": "facebook"
    }
]
```

I am expecting my api like this. with company_name.
And i wants to post the data from same api in rest framework
thanks,,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you'd defined the **`__str__()`** method in your **`Company`** model, you can use the [**`StringRelatedField()`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) as

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

**UPDATE**
override the **`to_representation`** method

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['company_name'] = instance.company_name.name
        return rep
```

Comment: i wants to post also

Comment: TypeError at /users/
super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: use `super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)` instead `super().to_representation(instance)`

Comment: Yes. Using `StringRelatedField()` is the simple one. But, the *comments* says that he needs to do ***write and update*** operations as well

Answer (score 11):

simple solution is use [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.CharField(source='company_name.name')
```

Comment: This is the simplest and one could add a company id as a field so that it could be used for forms in a js page (to represent the "company").

Answer (score 4):

Use depth.

```
class PhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_company_name')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
    def get_company_name(self, obj):
        return obj.company_name.name
```

Comment: i wants to post also

Comment: then change it to CharField

Comment: now my company input field is gone.. i need to post data also

Comment: @Exprator for your solution source does not need.

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['company_name'] = instance.company_name.name
        return rep
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/):

This worked for me:

```py
company_name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name')
```