# How to display field value instead of id for foreign key in Django Rest Framework ensuring all fields being displayed as before on DRF HTML form

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

**Model:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
        
        
class Gender(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender
        
        
class Details(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField()
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'


class GenderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Gender
        fields = '__all__'


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'dob', 'gender']
```

At present the output I get below output with the above in place:

```
[
    {
        "name": 1,
        "dob": "1990-05-19",
        "gender": 1
    }
]
```

where **id 1** for Person = **"John Smith"** and **id 1** for gender is **"Male"**. I got several solutions on stackoverflow such as:

- [How to get foreignkey field name insted of id in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491330/how-to-get-foreignkey-field-name-insted-of-id-in-django-rest-framework)
- [Retrieving a Foreign Key value with django-rest-framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers)

All of these methods work but then the Django Rest Framework makes the foreign keys as Read Only and the these fields are no longer seen in the DRF HTML Form. My question here is how to get to display foreign key field value instead of id ensuring **DRF HTML Form still shows those fields as earlier**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override the **`to_representation`** method of **`ProfileSerializer`** class

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'dob', 'gender']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['gender'] = GenderSerializer(instance.gender).data
        return rep
```

Comment: user:12578202 Thanks for the above. How can I use a similar method for converting ManyToManyField ids to their values in the to_representation.

Comment: Please do ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64079111/how-can-i-display-the-values-of-a-manytomany-field-in-django-rest-framework-inst

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wanto to override `to_representation()` , you can create a `SerializerMethodField`:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'dob', 'gender']

    # this method is called to get the value of field `name`
    def get_name(self, profile):
          return profile.name.name
```