# DRF + Serializer to return custom data from multiple models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670087/serialize-data-from-multiple-models-django) I am trying to return data from multiple models in one query by DRF.

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=nodels.CASCADE)
```

I want to return a JSON list of all options for albums and genres for all artists.

Something like:

```
{
    "genres": ["techno", "rap", "rock", ...],
    "albums": ["nevermind", "collection", "fragile", ...]
}
```

I created a custom serializer:

```
class InfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    albums = serializers.CharField()
    genres = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["albums", "genres"]
```

and a Viewset:

```
class OptionsViewSet(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = InfoSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        options = [{"albums": Album.objects.all()},
                   {"genres": Genre.objects.all()}]
        results = InfoSerializer(options, many = True)
        results.is_valid()
        return Response(results.data)
```

Error message I keep getting:

> KeyError when attempting to get value for field `albums` on serializer `InfoSerializer`
> ...

Answer (score 1):

You're giving options to the InfoSerializer, and that serializer assumes that `options` has an attribute named albums and genres. Since it doesn't have that, it raises an error. See the [drf documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers)

The design of your viewset looks like you're returning multiple instances but actually what you return is a single dictionary that has only two keys. Albums and genres are independent from each other, so returning an array with `many=True` doesn't make any sense here.

I'd suggest you return something like this in an APIView.
Also you can only retrieve the `album_name` and `genre_name` from database which will make this a bit more performant.

```
{
    "albums": list(Album.objects.all().values_list('album_name', flat=True)),
                   
    "genres": list(Genre.objects.all().values_list('genre_name', flat=True))
}
```

Comment: This works exactly the way I wanted - but now I am not using any serializer. How would the serializer look like if I may ask? Thanks!