# Python - Django: select mulitple fields from different models to serialize into one json result

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I'm currently working in my first Django project and am using the authentication mechanism that is included with Django. I currently have a game model with a foreign key relationship to a user in the auth_user table. Here are the following fields:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    game_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=10)
    host = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    join_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I currently have a view method that just grabs all of the active game objects, and then passes those results into a serializer that serializes the data to be returned to the client.

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    games = Game.objects.filter(active__exact=True)
    serializer = GameSerializer(games, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to add the username and email fields that are in AUTH_USER_MODEL to the results to be serialized, but I haven't been able to find examples of adding specific fields from a related model to the results that are serialized. Basically, I'm trying to figure out the django model equivalent of the following SQL statement

```
select u.username, u.email, g.* from game g
inner join AUTH_USER_MODEL u on u.user_id = g.host_id
```

Finally, once I have the results from that sort of query, how would I serialize the combined objects? Do I need to create another model that's a combination of the two models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, I can use a nested serializer, here's the stack overflow answer that pointed me in the right direction: [Serialize data from multiple models django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670087/serialize-data-from-multiple-models-django#54670223)

Here is the Django rest framework documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer should look like this -

```
class AuthUserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthUserModel
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auth = AuthUserModelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

Use your serializer where you want -

```
serializer = GameSerializer()
```

Now in your serializer response, you will get all the fields from `game` model and `username,email` from `auth_user_model`.

Comment: I'm using exactly that for my serializer, unfortunately I'm now running into this exception when hitting the API:

"AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `GameSerializer`.

web_1  | The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Game` instance.

web_1  | Original exception text was: 'Game' object has no attribute 'user'."

Comment: I think the exception is right because I can't see the `user` attribute on your GAME model. My provided code is just to give you an idea change things accordingly