# DRF Serializer - How to return field of a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good morning,

I am really struggling with an issue returning a value from my Django Rest Framework API.

I have two models, SirTarget & Status.  The SirTarget is like a ticket & the Status is a textual status label of the ticket that corresponds to the phase of handling the ticket.

The models are as follows:

```
class Status(models.Model):
     status_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     status_open = models.BooleanField(default=1)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.status_text


 class SirTarget(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
     entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     sir_status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, related_name='targets')

     def __str__(self):
        return '%d - %s %s' % (self.id, self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

My serializer looks like this:

```
 class SirTargetStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     status_text = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='Status.status_text')

     class Meta:
         model = SirTarget
         fields = '__all__'
```

The field status_text is not coming back as part of the API call.  When I return the data, I receive the PK of the Status table (1,2,3, etc.) but I do not receive the status_text field.

I have been messing around with this for a while and struggling.  I have referenced similar set ups such as in this post:
[Retrieving a Foreign Key value with django-rest-framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers)

However, nothing seems to be working for me.

***EDIT***

I have also tried:

```
status_text = serializers.RelatedField(source='sir_status.status_text', read_only=True)
```

and

```
status_text = serializers.CharField(source='sir_status.status_text', read_only=True)
```

When I look directly in the DB, I see what I am looking for and verified that the values are populated as expected:

```
# select * from sir_admin_status;
 id |  status_text   | status_open 
----+----------------+-------------
  1 | New            | t
  2 | Open           | t
  3 | Referred       | f
  4 | Resolved       | f
  5 | False Positive | f
```

DRF 3.9.0
Python 3.7.1

Thank you for your help.

BCBB

Comment: What *exactly* is wrong with the answer given by Tom (the actual author of DRF) in that linked answer? There he is using RelatedField. Why aren't you?

Comment: RelatedField is still not returning it either.  Neither is the CharField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do

```
class SirTargetStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     status_text = serializers.CharField(source='sir_status.status_text', read_only=True)

     class Meta:
         model = SirTarget
         fields = ('name', ... , 'status_text') # explicitly define all field you want here
```

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  ReadOnlyField wasn't working and I messed up some OTHER things while trying to figure it out.  Once I got those changes backed off. I tried the CharField as suggested and its working as expected.   Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To access all the fields in the foreign key table use "depth"

```
class SirTargetStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
         model = SirTarget
         fields = ('__all__')
         depth = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! A much simpler method, given that you can then consume the FK fields as needed, rather than specifying every field.