# Get fields of foreign key in serializer django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm 2 weeks into django so this might be dumb!
In my django project, I have 3 models, Teacher, Student and a CustomUser. CustomUser has 2 fields first_name and last_name. Student has 3 fields grade, field_of_study and user which is a foreign key to CustomUser.
Now inside my StudentSerializer I want to serialize first_name, last_name, grade and field of study. But because the last 2 field are not direct fields of Student, I cannot do that. Anyone know how this should be handled?

I also came across this [Retrieving a Foreign Key value with django-rest-framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers) but the answer didn't help really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and it worked like a charm. Hope the answer helps a newbie in the future!

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField()
firstname = serializers.CharField(source='user.firstname')
lastname = serializers.CharField(source='user.lastname')

class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'id', 'school', 'field_of_study')
```